# How to insert text box value in database on combo box selected item?

Tags: c#

I designed one login form and in that I used combobox1, textbox1, textbox2 and button. When I select "Admin" in combobox the username and password in textbox1 and textbox2 will checked from Admin table in database if username and password is correct then show the Admin Form.

How can I do this?

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "Admin") 
    { 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Admin");
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

        if (dr.Read()) 
        { 
            textBox1.Text = dr["Username"].ToString(); 
            textBox2.Text = dr["Password"].ToString(); 
            Admin ad = new Admin(); 
            ad.ShowDialog(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try something first, then show code examples to explain where you are stuck or what went wrong

Comment: You can access the value of the selected item in the combobox. Depending on this value, change your SQL.

Comment: the admin form did not opened.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you're actually trying to set the value of `textbox1` and `textbox2`from the values you have in the database. I'm guessing you're actually trying to check if they're equal?

If so you're better off modifying your query so it returns only the details from Admin based on the details entered by the user rather than returning everything from the admin table.

Also, as per Alfie Goodacre's answer, you want `SelectedItem`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Admin") 
    { 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * 
                                         from Admin 
                                         where Username = @UN and 
                                               Password = @PW");

        var unParam = new SqlParameter("@UN", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        unParam.Value = textbox1.text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(unParam);

        var pwParam = new SqlParameter("@PW", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        pwParam.Value = textbox2.text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pwParam);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

        //check if any data has returned based on the user inputs
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            if (dr.Read()) 
            {  
                Admin ad = new Admin(); ad.ShowDialog(); 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank You. its useful to my application.

Comment: @AjitNimbalkar - if this answered your question please mark it as the correct answer by clicking the tick next to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You do not want selected text as your check, you want `SelectedItem` - this is because the `Button_Click` event removes focus from the box, effectively deselecting any text in it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Admin") 
    { 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Admin");
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

        if (dr.Read()) 
        { 
            textBox1.Text = dr["Username"].ToString(); 
            textBox2.Text = dr["Password"].ToString(); 
            Admin ad = new Admin(); ad.ShowDialog(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is still not correct as the text of textBox1 and textBox2 are being set. They're not being checked for equality, which is presumably the whole point of this exercise, to check if someone is an admin or not.